# Google Sattelite map switch Business POI

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to show google Sattelite map without Business POIs and realy cant find some information about how to do it.

I tryed google.maps.StyledMapType stylers, but these are not available for sattelite mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:**

It's possible to hide some map data from base map types by changing `styles` map option. In your case you have to style MapTypeId.HYBRID, you cannot style MapTypeId.SATELLITE. Your map options then should be something like:

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    styles: [
        {
            featureType: "poi.business",
            elementType: "all",
            stylers: [
                { visibility: "off" }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Tomik i know how to manage map types.
I need to hide Points of Interrest from that map, but cannot find way how to remove POI's from sattelite map.
How i said - Map Styling is available only for ROADMAP

Comment: So you want just to remove business POIs from HYBRID map and keep all the other data? That's possible. I edited the answer, hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi Tomik, iam sorry but it looks like google updated its maps and i cannot reproduce original problematic state (with Business POIs) :-/ . And just one more thing - iam off course using HYBRID map type, i was confused by it's "Satelitte" button in controls. Ill comback and check this out once the problem occours again.